# Why aren't these function signatures treated the same?

Tags: c++, function, templates, lambda, function-pointers

I must be misunderstanding something because I thought the two cases are the same:

```
#include <iostream>

    void function() { std::cout << "Hi\n"; }

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<void(*)()> funcPtrVec;
        std::vector<void()> funcVec;

        funcPtrVec.push_back(function); // Works 
        funcVec.push_back(function);    // Works

        auto lambdaFunc = []() { std::cout << "Hi\n"; };

        funcPtrVec.push_back(lambdaFunc);   // Works
        funcVec.push_back(lambdaFunc);      // Doesn't work

    }
```

Now, in both cases my compiler says that the function signatures are the same, void function() and void lambdaFunc(). I really thought that when a lambda function doesn't capture anything it behaves like a free function, which the same signatures would seem to support. Also, I guess I'm confused even more due to the fact that in the following all seem to be treated the same, as if decaying to the same thing:

```
void function() { std::cout << "Hi\n"; }

void funcTakingFunc(void()) {}
void funcTakingFuncPtr(void(*)()) {}

int main()
{
    auto lambdaFunc = []() { std::cout << "Hi\n"; };
    void(*funcPtr)() = lambdaFunc;  // Works

    funcTakingFuncPtr(lambdaFunc);  // Works
    funcTakingFuncPtr(funcPtr);     // Works
    funcTakingFunc(lambdaFunc);     // Works
    funcTakingFunc(funcPtr);        // Works
    // They all work
}
```

So as far as I can see the only distinction between the function and the function pointer made is when given as a template argument to vector. This obviously means I don't understand templates well, but what's the reason for this? Because the two really seem the same from the examples I tried.

Comment: Your second example is actually a special case in parameter lists: If you declare a parameter to be a function, it is silently treated as a pointer to a function. In other words, `void foo()` is equivalent to `void (*foo)()` (but only in a parameter list).

Comment: @melpomene That's strange though because in vector<void(*)()> , what's between the angled brackets isn't a function parameter, is it? I can push_back a function and it's decaying into a function pointer?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with your vector.

Comment: In the vector example you have two different vectors, one that takes pointers to functions, and one that takes actual functions. Now, the latter vector shouldn't actually compile, since internally it tries to create an array of functions which is not allowed. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b888be8eef55ff9

Comment: I see, I'm using Visual Studio, I guess it's a compiler bug. Well that's good news I suppose, because it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<void()>` is not allowed; the type must be an *object type*, and a function type is not an object type.

There are various parts of the specification of vector requirements we could identify as being violated by a non-object type; the most obvious is the default allocator.  In the table in [allocator.requirements]/2 it is specified that the type the allocator is for must be an object type.